# Graph databases and Delphi?

Tags: delphi, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm interested in storing graph data (nodes linked to each other via relationships) into a database.

The common answers around here recommend to use graph databases instead of SQL-based ones, such as Neo4J.

However there isn't any Delphi driver for this database, and I'm curious to see how Delphi developers are approaching these kinds of problems:

Are there any DBs available? Are we settling for an SQL database? Or maybe opting for one anyway?

Comment: Most offer some form of HTTP/REST interface usable from Delphi. There is nothing standardized in the graph DB world like there is for SQL. Each has it's own query language and access methods. For neo4j that would be: https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/4.4/introduction/

Comment: There is https://7687.org/ if you want to implement the client for what's known as the Bolt protocol.

Comment: @Brian There *is* an upcoming standard for the graph world: https://www.gqlstandards.org/

Comment: @fbiville this is unrelated to Facebook's graphql, right?